# Hahn-Banach Theorem: Proof verification

Tags: convex-analysis, solution-verification

If my proof for the following problem correct?

> Prove: If $X$ is a preordered linear space such that $\mathrm{al}$-$\mathrm{int}_{X}\left(X_{+}\right) \neq \emptyset$, then there exists a nonzero positive functional on $X$.

Take an arbitrary $x$ from $X$ (This exists from $\mathrm{al}$-$\mathrm{int}_{X}\left(X_{+}\right) \neq \emptyset$). Since $X$ is a linear space, then the set $Y=\{y\in X| y=\lambda x,\lambda\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a linear subspace of $X$. Define $L$ as $L(\lambda x)=\lambda$. Obviously, $L\in \mathcal{L}(X,\mathbb{R})$.Using Hahn Banach's theorem, $Y$ can be extended to $X$.
This is the nonzero positive functional that we want.
Q.E.D